# (Unity3d) Play other TimeLineAsset in Playable Director with Blend?

Tags: unity-game-engine, timeline

I have a character with a Playable Director and "idle" TimeLineAsset. 
When user touch on character, i want to play other different TimeLineAsset that called "Pickup", so character walk and pickup weapons. 
i think correct way is change TimeLineAsset but there is a problem.
second timelineasset that played, doesnt blend in with last animation in first TimeLineAsset, so it has a sudden jump to play when i change timeLineAsset.

im new in PlayableDirector and i dont know if there is a better way ? 
have i handle this just in one TimeLineAsset ? or i have correct way.

Thanks for Help.